# Vendor reference not being copied from VB Library project to C# Application

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a library of business logic written in VB.NET. It references some DLLs from vendors, these are set to Copy Local = true. When I build this VB.NET project, I can browse to its bin directory and confirm that everything was correctly copied.

Now I have a C# ASP.NET MVC application that references the VB.NET library project. I can build the C# application, but when I browse to its bin directory, only the VB.NET DLL is there, and all the vendor references that the VB.NET DLL needs are NOT there.

That is,

```
Dependency chain is:
C# MVC -> VB.NET library -> Vendor library

MyLibrary\bin folder contains:
MyLibrary.dll, MyVendor.dll

MyMVC\bin folder contains:
MyMVC.dll, MyLibrary.dll (MyVendor.dll is missing!)
```

Why is this not copying, and how do I make it?

Workarounds like setting up a post-build action are not going to work, as this is going into Microsoft Azure, and files copied post-build do not get bundled into the .cspkg deployment file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References are not transitive.
You need to add a reference to the vendor library to the C# project too.

Comment: I should have mentioned this ONLY happens with a mix of VB.NET/C# code. If all projects are C#, everything gets copied just fine.